# How to prove $\limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} = \limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{ \left |(k+1)a_{k+1} \right|}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, limsup-and-liminf

I'm doing Problem II.9.3 in textbook *Analysis I* by Amann.

> [image]

**My attempt:**

To prove that both series have the same radius of convergence. I need to show $$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} = \limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{ \left |(k+1)a_{k+1} \right|}$$

Because $$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{ \left |(k+1)\right|} = 1$$ I have to show $$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} = \limsup_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{ \left |a_{k+1} \right|}$$

I'm stuck from here.

Could you please give me some hints to finish the proof? Thank you so much!

---

**Update:** Thanks to Botond's answer, I added the most important part here. All credits go to Botond.

Let $c = \limsup \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}$ and $d = \limsup \sqrt[k]{|a_{k+1}|}$.

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} \le c + \varepsilon$ and $\sqrt[k]{|a_{k+1}|} \le d +\varepsilon$ for all $k \ge N$.

We have $|a_k| \le (c+\varepsilon)^{k}$, consequently $|a_{k+1}| \le (c+\varepsilon)^{k+1}$, and consequently $|a_{k+1}|^{1/k} \le (c+\varepsilon)^{(k+1)/k}$ for all $k \ge N$. Take the limit $k \to \infty$, we get $$d = \limsup \sqrt[k]{|a_{k+1}|} \le \limsup (c+\varepsilon)^{(k+1)/k} = c+\varepsilon ,\quad \varepsilon >0$$

Take the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$, we get $d \le c$.

We have $|a_{k+1}| \le (d+\varepsilon)^{k}$ and consequently $|a_{k+1}|^{1/(k+1)} \le (d+\varepsilon)^{k/(k+1)}$ for all $k \ge N$. Take the limit $k \to \infty$, we get $$c =\limsup \sqrt[k]{|a_{k}|} = \limsup \sqrt[k+1]{|a_{k+1}|} \le \limsup (d+\varepsilon)^{k/(k+1)} = d+\varepsilon ,\quad \varepsilon >0$$

Take the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$, we get $c \le d$.

As such, $c = d$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Hint: $x^{1/(k+1)} = (x^{1/k})^{k/(k+1)}.$

Comment: Hi @zhw, your hint lead me to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343260/let-lim-k-to-infty-x-k-a-and-lim-k-to-infty-y-k-b-does-lim?noredirect=1&lq=1, which is out of my capability. I'm only at convergence section in my textbook. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Couldn’t you just take a monotone subsequence that “goes to the sup” and then multiply and divide by the $(a_{k+1})^{\frac{1}{k+1}}$?

Comment: @tommy1996q but how to prove $\left(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}} \to 1$?

Comment: If the limit of the sequence is bounded, that is a Cauchy sequence and you should be able to do that. If it is not bounded, then the original problem is easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing your work:

Let $c:=\lim\sup |a_n|^{1/n}$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ be given. Then we have that (for big enough $n$):
$$|a_n|\leqslant (c+\varepsilon)^n$$
This means that
$$|a_{n+1}|\leqslant (c+\varepsilon)^{n+1}$$
$$|a_{n+1}|^{1/n}\leqslant (c+\varepsilon)^{1+1/n}$$
I think you can finish this direction, and work out the other direction as well.

Comment: I'm unable to understand your reasoning. Could you please more more specific? This question inspires me to ask a related one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343260/let-lim-k-to-infty-x-k-a-and-lim-k-to-infty-y-k-b-does-lim/3343301?noredirect=1#comment6881651_3343301). If you don't mind, please have a look at it.

Comment: @LeAnhDung With my work, you can show that $\lim \sup |a_{n+1}|^{1/n} \leqslant \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$. And I think you can get a similar inequality, but the other way around, which will imply that they are equal.

Comment: @LeAnhDung With my work, you can show that $\lim \sup |a_{n+1}|^{1/n} \leqslant \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$. And I think you can get a similar inequality, but the other way around, which will imply that they are equal.

Comment: For big enough $n$, we have $|a_{n}|^{1/n}\leqslant c+\varepsilon$ and $|a_{n+1}|^{1/n}\leqslant (c+\varepsilon)^{1+1/n}$. I'm unable to understand how your proceed to show $\lim \sup |a_{n+1}|^{1/n} \leqslant \lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$. Please elaborate more!

Comment: @LeAnhDung the RHS is $(c+\varepsilon)(c+\varepsilon)^{1/n}$. The second term goes to one, so taking th $\lim \sup$ of both sides, the RHS will be $c+\varepsilon$. Since it's true $\forall \varepsilon >0$, we will get that the LHS is $\leqslant c$.

Comment: Thank you so much :))))))) I got your ideas and update my proof to reflect your answer.

Comment: @LeAnhDung You're welcome. You can use similar argument a lot of time when you are dealing with $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$. For example, when you are proving the Stolz-Cesàro theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Prove that, if $\{u_n\}$ is a bounded non-negative sequence and $\{v_n\}$ is a non-negative sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n=v$.Then,
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(u_nv_n)=v(\limsup_{n\to\infty} u_n)$

Comment: I know the property you mentioned, but I don't know how to apply it in this problem. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: The sequence $\{n^{\frac{1}{n}}\}$ is a convergent sequence which converges to $1$.Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I already used that property in my proof.